# SimpleHTTPServer code 404, message File not found

Tags: javascript, python, json, apache, d3.js

I am trying to run a simple d3 Javascript program to visualise a graph. I also have a JSON file for this graph. In order to get the program run, I was told that I should follow the following steps:

1- On the terminal, I go to the folder where the project is.
2- I insert the following command: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 &`
3- On the Web Browser (Firefox), I add this: `http://localhost:8888`

When I do the third step, the terminal shows me the following error message:

```
localhost - - [11/Nov/2013 08:07:23] code 404, message File not found
localhost - - [11/Nov/2013 08:07:23] "GET /D3/sample.json HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Here is my HTML file for d3 Javascript graph:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<style>

.node {
   stroke: #fff;
   stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
   stroke: #999;
   stroke-opacity: .6; 
}

</style> 
<body>
<p> Paragraph !!! </p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
.charge(-120)
.linkDistance(30)
.size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

d3.json("sample.json", function(error, graph) {
force
  .nodes(graph.nodes)
  .links(graph.links)
  .start();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(graph.links)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
  .call(force.drag);

node.append("title")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

force.on("tick", function() {
   link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
   .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
   .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
   .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
   .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
});
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems that the JSON file `sample.json` can not be read as what message above displays. Could anyone please help me how to get that program run and get the json file read using the command I have provided above. If I add a header and paragraphs in that HTML file, they will appear but cant manage to display the graph. Is there any problem with the location of the JSON file or is there something wrong with the `d3.v3.js` file? Thank you for your assistance in advance.

`

Comment: I experienced a similar 404 error and for some reason the server did not accept my actual directory path. So I removed the path and put the .js library files in the same directory where the html file was located. That worked.

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand you have set-up a python simple server in a directory and in that directory you have a html file which display's in the browser. However, when you try to run the js code and load a json file you get a 404 error.

The error say's that it's looking for the json file in a directory called D3, however, you code is looking for the json in the root directory.  Try changing the

`D3.json("sample.json", function(error, graph)`

line to

`d3.json("D3/sample.json", function(error, graph)`.

Also, inside the function call place `console.log(graph)` like this:

```
d3.json("sample.json", function(error, graph) {
    console.log(graph)
```

This send output to your console so you can check what's being read in (apologies if you already knew that).